# C++ Builder [bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(18): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly

Tags: c++

Trying to import the Crypt32.dll but its not working isn't this c++?

Am using RadStudio C++ Builder how can i import DLL like Crypt32.dll etc?

Someone show me the right way thank you.

```
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=System::Runtime::InteropServices::CharSet::Auto)]
static bool CryptData(DATA_BLOB %pDataIn, System::String ^szDataDescr, DATA_BLOB %pOptionalEntropy, IntPtr pvReserved, CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT %pPromptStruct, int dwFlags, DATA_BLOB %pDataOut);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... isn't this c++?

`System::String ^szDataDescr` is using Microsofts c++-cli extension syntax for managed objects. So no, it's not standard c++ syntax.

Same for `DATA_BLOB %pDataIn`.

To cite from their [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xey702bw(v=vs.90).aspx):

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the info